# Removing Incorrect Labels within Tidyverse/ Limiting Actions of as_factor()

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm working with British Election Study data. To be used in R, this first has to be converted from the .dta form provided, which I think puts labels on to a lot of variables. Most of the time this is useful, but I think a problem I've got is where this isn't the case.

Using `as_factor()` blindly converts all variables with labels to factors. Is there a way to specify that only certain vectors are converted ? i.e

```
new_df <- data %>%
          as_factor(just_this_column)
```

Failing that, is there a good way to remove the labels of certain variables within a dataframe ? I've kooked at the `sjlabelled` package but this does something weird and converts the data from a dataframe:

```
example_data<- str(sjlabelled::remove_all_labels(example_data$generalElectionVoteW19))
```

The reason I'm trying to do all of this is to make a histogram of number of people voting for each party (the factor) at a certain age. In this dataset, the age variable has a label which is messing up the code.

Of course, I could just convert the factor to a numeric value at the end but this seems like a messy way of achieving things !

Here is the dput:

```
structure(list(ageW19 = structure(c(72, 52, 39, 75, 26, 56), label = "Age", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(`Not Asked` = -9, 
Skipped = -8), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), generalElectionVoteW19 = structure(c(1, 13, 3, 1, 2, 1), label = "General election vote intention (recalled vote in post-election waves)", format.stata = "%40.0g", labels = c(`I would/did not vote` = 0, 
Conservative = 1, Labour = 2, `Liberal Democrat` = 3, `Scottish National Party (SNP)` = 4, 
`Plaid Cymru` = 5, `United Kingdom Independence Party (UKIP)` = 6, 
`Green Party` = 7, `British National Party (BNP)` = 8, Other = 9, 
`Change UK- The Independent Group` = 11, `Brexit Party` = 12, 
`An independent candidate` = 13, `Don't know` = 9999), class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = c(`1` = 1L, `3` = 3L, `5` = 5L
))
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your first questions, you need `mutate` to convert a single column, e.g.

```
new_df  <- data %>%
  mutate(factor_column = as_factor(old column))
```

However, as you said you probably want to convert to numeric type, so you might want to use `as.numeric` instead of `as_factor`.

Comment: Ah thank - you ! Is there an intuitive reason why this must be done, or is it simply the way things are ? And yes I should clarify, for my histogram I have an age - a double -  and a number of people at each age inherent in the dataset. I'm using the histogram to count this whilst splitting it up by party support.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with „why this must be done“? Why WHAT must be done which way?

Comment: I suppose I find it confusing that `mutate` must be used to achieve this and I guess I find it a little peeving that it isn't shown as an example in any documentation ! Forgive me, I think I've just been going around in circles trying to do this all day !

Comment: Well, it‘s quite logical. Assuming you are using the tidyverse (because of using the %>% pipe) it‘s clear that you want to use mutate, because you are operating on a certain column, i.e change it. And also not sure what you expect on terms of documentation. mutate is from the tidyverse, whereas the label handling comes from another package, so neither has to provide examples for using the respective other function. Might bw a bit confusing if you are only starting with R, but it gets easier over time.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `base R`

```
data$factor_column <- factor(data$old_column)
```